# Adding a second textview to customAdapter ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

So I have a listview with one textview and I want to add a second textview to it. But I cannot figure out how to modify the adapter and then call it in my main activity, even after looking through many similiar questions on stackoverflow.

Heres how my CustomAdapter.java is now

```
 class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>{

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, CharSequence[] routes) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_row ,routes);
    }

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater routeInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = convertView;
    if(customView == null){customView = routeInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);}

    CharSequence singleRoute = getItem(position);
    TextView routeText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.routeText);
    routeText.setText(singleRoute);

    ///// Textview I want to add
    CharSequence routeNum = getItem(position);
    TextView routeNumText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.numbersTextView);
    routeNumText.setText(routeNum);
    /////
    return customView;
```

and heres my MainActivity.java

```
 ///// fill listview numbers I want to add
    final String[] routeListviewNumbers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.routeNumbers);
    //fill list view with xml array of routes
    final String[] routeListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.routeList);

   //custom adapter for list view
    ListAdapter routeAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, routeListViewItems);
    final ListView routeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.routeListView);
    routeListView.setAdapter(routeAdapter);
```

any help in how to modify the adapter and then call it in the main activity would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you run your app? How does this differ from what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a custom Route class since this adapter is meant to handle one array. Create some member variables for the route number and route items in the new class with getter and setter methods. Then you should be able to create a new array list of Route objects in your main activity and iterate through the existing string arrays while appending them (as new Route objects) to the new array.

You will have to change the adapter to accept a Route object instead of CharSequence. Hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a custom adapter for you.
Exm..
Create Route Class

```
class Route{
     public int number;
     public String text;
}
```

Base Adapter...

```
public class myBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<Route> mRouteList;

public BilgiAdapter(Activity activity,List<Route> routeList){
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mRouteList = routeList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mRouteList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mRouteList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View myView;
    myView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.line_layout,null);
    Route r = mRouteList.get(position);

    TextView txtRouteNumber = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.textRouteNumber);
    TextView txtRouteText = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.textRouteText);

    txtRouteNumber.setText(String.ValueOf(r.number));
    txtRouteText.setText(String.ValueOf(r.text));
    return myView;
}
```

}

MainActivity vs..

```
ListView lstRoute;
myBaseAdapter adapter;
List<Route> list;
...
..
..
..
..
OnCreate(..)
..
list = new ArrayList<Route>();
//add routes in list
myBaseAdapter = new myBaseAdapter(MainActivity.this,list);
lstRoute = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewRoute);
lstRoute.setAdapter(myBaseAdapter);
...
..
..
```

line_layout.xml(Layout file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textRouteNumber"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/textRouteText"/>

</LinearLayout>
```